# How to navigate other screen using react navigation 5

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have currently problem on my onpress moving screen. it says that undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate') **the main objective is when I press this text my screen will move on policy screen.** Just a give more details, I created navigation.js component inside of this component I created stack screen for (Login, Register, Policy) so now, I have task where when I press the check icon modal will popup on the register screen. inside of that modal there is a Policy clickable text where when I press that text my screen will move to the Stack.Screen Policy.

**Onpress function:**

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Policy')}
```

**Stack Screen:**

```
 <Stack.Screen 
     name="Policy" 
     component={PrivacyPolicy} 
     options={{
        headerShown: false,
     }}
 />
```

**Error:**

[image: Error]

**Whole Code:**

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Login from '../screens/Login';
import Register from '../screens/Register';
import PrivacyPolicy from '../screens/PrivacyPolicy';
import {Button,TouchableOpacity,View,Modal,Text, Alert, TouchableHighlight, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import {Overlay} from 'react-native-elements';
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class Navigator extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            modalVisible: false
        }
    }

    setModalVisible = (visible) => {
        this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
    }

    PrivacyModalShow() {
        const { modalVisible } = this.state;

        return (
        <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            visible={modalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => {
                this.setModalVisible(false);
            }}
            >
                <ScrollView>
                    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                        <View style={styles.modalView}>

                            <Text style={styles.modalText}>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ac enim odio. Curabitur at dui a velit bibendum aliquet. Suspendisse elit erat, posuere eget tellus eget, maximus tristique sapien. Integer ornare erat a turpis aliquam, et scelerisque metus congue. Nulla turpis ante, rutrum ac massa egestas, ultrices blandit est. Etiam lectus nisl, viverra vel gravida quis, lacinia nec sapien. Etiam eu facilisis leo. Duis ac aliquam ante. Donec vel velit ipsum. Morbi tempor erat consectetur, aliquet augue nec,
                                tristique nibh. In hendrerit sem non aliquet convallis. Donec molestie mauris sit amet quam posuere euismod.
                            </Text>

                            <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                                <CheckBox
                                />
                                <Text style={styles.label}>I have read and agree to the <Text onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Policy')} style={{textDecorationLine:'underline', color:'#4ABDFF', fontWeight:'bold', fontSize:17}}>terms and condition and data privacy policy</Text></Text>
                            </View>

                            <View style={styles.confirmationContainer}>
                                <Text style={{fontSize:17,textAlign:"right",flex:1, fontWeight:'bold'}} onPress={() => {
                                this.setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                                }}>No</Text>
                                <Text style={{marginLeft:30,fontSize:17,textAlign:"right",  color:'#4ABDFF', fontWeight:'bold'}}>Yes, Agree</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </Modal>
        )
    }

    render() {        
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
               
                    <Stack.Navigator>
                        <Stack.Screen 
                            name="Login" 
                            component={Login} 
                            options={{
                                headerShown: false,
                            }}
                        />

                        <Stack.Screen 
                            name="Registration" 
                            component={Register} 
                            options={{
                                headerStyle: {
                                    backgroundColor: '#4ABDFF'
                                },
                                headerTitleStyle: {
                                    color: '#fff',
                                },
                                headerTintColor:'#fff',
                                headerRight: () => (
                                    <View style={{flexDirection: "row",justifyContent: "flex-end",paddingRight:10,width: 120}}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                        onPress={() => this.setModalVisible(true) }
                                        >
                                        <Icon type="font-awesome" name="check" size={20} color="white" />
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                ),
                            }}
                        
                        />

                        <Stack.Screen 
                            name="Policy" 
                            component={PrivacyPolicy} 
                            options={{
                                headerShown: false,
                            }}
                        />
                </Stack.Navigator>
                {this.PrivacyModalShow()}
            </NavigationContainer>
            
        );
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    centeredView: {
      marginTop: 22,
      width:'100%'

    },
    checkboxContainer: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        marginBottom: 0,
    },
    confirmationContainer: {
        flexDirection: "row",
    },
    label: {
        margin: 6,
        fontSize:17
    },
    confirmationLabel: {
        
        fontSize:17,
        textAlign:'right',
        flex:1
    },
    modalView: {
      margin: 30,
      backgroundColor: "white",
      borderRadius: 5,
      padding: 35,
      shadowOpacity: 0.5,
      shadowRadius: 2,
      elevation: 5,
      maxWidth:'100%'
    },
    textStyle: {
      color: "white",
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
    modalText: {
      marginBottom: 5,
      fontSize:17,
    }
});
  

export default Navigator;
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `PrivacyModalShow()` function into an arrow function:

```
PrivacyModalShow = () => {

...

}
```

Or bind `this` to the `PrivacyModalShow()` inside the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.PrivacyModalShow = this.PrivacyModalShow.bind(this);

    ...
}
```

Comment: @DevGe Can you explain?